# Matrix with only 0s and 1s

Tags: linear-algebra

We have a symmetric $n \times n$ matrix with only $0$s and $1$s, where the elements along the diagonal are all $1$s. Prove that the vector $1_n$ (only $1$s $n$ times) is in the column space of the matrix.

Might be well-known, but my linear algebra is stale. Please explain it step-by-step.